# Snoop utility for WPF apps is not working - does it support WPF 4?

Tags: wpf, snoop

I have a WPF 4 application running on Windows XP.  When I run Snoop, it picks up the application, however when I click on "Snoop this application" nothing happens.  Also when I click on the magnifying glass nothing happens.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new version of Snoop supports WPF 4 (http://www.cplotts.com/2010/02/14/snoop-now-supports-wpf-4-0/).

Which version are you using?

Comment: must have picked up an older version - went back and made sure I got it from the codeplex this time and things work fine now - thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are running your application in administrator mode then Snoop will not work unless you don't run your Snoop in administrator mode , so better check what privilege you have given to Snoop.

Answer (score 1):

**The latest and greatest version of Snoop is always available at http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com.**

One thing to note is that the source code (available for download) is usually somewhat out of date ... as compared to the released bits which you can download an installer for. That is, I don't release Snoop for every fix/change I make.

For example, the currently released version is v2.6.0 ... but I have 9 work items marked for v2.6.1. Check out the [Issue Tracker](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/workitem/list/advanced?ProjectName=snoopwpf) for more info on what is in each version.

Comment: I should also mention that I have made several changes so that Snoop better recognizes WPF 4.0 applications. There have been several issues where WPF 4.0 applications weren't showing up in the app chooser. If that is your problem, definitely download the latest source code and build it.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem, but only with the msi (the installer). So, I downloaded the source code and rebuilt Snoop on my machine, and after this, it all works fine.